# Error al usar __construct en un hijo de una clase de MySQL (se soluciona al no usar __construct pero lo necesito si o si)

Tags: php

Tengo dos clases:
La primera se llama "MySQL" y contiene todas las funciones para las consultas (además de las que trae la API "MySQLi). Utiliza __construct para crear el objeto MySQLi.
La segunda (Usuarios), que es la hija de la anterior, utiliza un __construct para instanciar otras clases necesarias.

Al hacer uso de __construct en la clase "Usuarios", me devuelve un error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in D:\Lautaro\Aplicaciones\Programas\Xampp\htdocs\src\classes\MySQL.php.

Si elimino __construct y sus sentencias, el error se soluciona, pero necesito SI o SI hacer esas instancias.

MySQL.php

```
namespace Brax\BBDD;

  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/cfg.php';

  class MySQL {
    private $server;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    public $mysqli; // Ver si la visibilidad afecta a los traits

    public function __construct() {
      $this->server   = 'localhost';
      $this->username = 'root';
      $this->password = '';
      $this->database = 'db';

      $this->mysqli = new \mysqli($this->server, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
      $this->mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    }

    /**
     * This function will make a query to the DB.
     * @param  string $sql       [It's a SQL string]
     * @return object|false      [If succesfull, it will return an object, else, it will return false]
     */
    protected function query(string $sql) {
      if (!empty($sql)) {
        if ($response = $this->mysqli->query($sql)) {
          if (DEBUG === true) {
            echo '['.HOUR.'] MySQLi query() DEBUG [SQL Executed]: '.$sql.PHP_EOL;
          }

          return $response;
        } else {
          if (DEBUG === true) {
            echo '['.HOUR.'] MySQLi query() DEBUG [SQL Executed with ERROR * ]: '.$sql.PHP_EOL;
          }

          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (DEBUG === true) {
          echo '['.HOUR.'] MySQLi Query DEBUG [SQL]: The query is empty.'.PHP_EOL;
        }

        return false;
      }
    }
```

Usuarios.php

```
namespace Brax\Usuarios;
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/cfg.php';
  spl_autoload_register('Brax\autoload');

  class Usuarios extends \Brax\BBDD\MySQL {
    use \Brax\Traits\CRUDTrait;

    private $Panel,
        $Accesos,
        $Referidos,
        $GameServers;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->Panel       = new \Brax\Panel\Panel();
      $this->Accesos     = new Accesos\Accesos();
      $this->Referidos   = new \Brax\Referidos\PostsReferidos();
      $this->GameServers = new \Brax\GameServers\GameServers();
    }
}
```

Debería funcionar la clase Usuarios con __construct, y no retornar el error que explique anteriormente.

Comment: @gbianchi acabo de llamar al constructor del padre en el constructor hijo y funciono. Hay alguna forma de ahorrar llamarlo desde el mismo? no funciona ponerle () al final del nombre de la clase padre en el extends. Gracias!!

Comment: Ahi te puse una respuesta, y todos los links correspondientes.. Te pido por favor que leas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio, y tambien que leas [ask] para que tus preguntas sean todavia mejores!!! bienvenido!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentacion sobre extends no es totalmente clara en cuanto a la relación padre e hijo y que pasa con sus constructores.

Si el hijo no tiene constructor, se llama al constructor del padre.. pero si el hijo tiene un constructor.. ahi se encuentra el problema.

Mas abajo, en uno de los [comentarios](http://php.net/manual/it/keyword.extends.php#62558), queda mucho mas claro cual es el problema.

Resulta que hay que llamar explicitamente al padre (como se hace en algunos lenguajes, algunos hacen la llamada implicitamente), para conseguir que se ejecute el mismo (y tambien, segun los comentarios, para ver todas las variables)

Entonces, a tu codigo, le falta la siguiente linea en el constructor del hijo:

```
parent::__construct();
```

En la documentacion sobre [constructores](http://php.net/manual/it/oop4.constructor.php) lo aclara especificamente:

> Attenzione
>
> PHP doesn't call constructors of the base class automatically from a
>   constructor of a derived class. It is your responsibility to propagate
>   the call to constructors upstream where appropriate.

Comment: Sos un genio! Cuando me dijiste que había que llamarlo en uno de los primeros comentarios, puse esa misma línea que me dijiste y funciono!. Llevo años viendo esta pagina y nunca creí que la iba a utilizar, muchas gracias! Voy a empezar a responder en lo que pueda.

Comment: Estoy hace varios días tratando de solucionar el problema, desarmando el código, leyendo la documentación (y también leí la de extends pero me salte esa parte), y me salvaste.

Comment: La documentacion sobre constructores era mas concisa al respecto.. pero no aclaraba el como hacerlo.. que bueno que funciono ;) @LautaroAguirre